# Multiline textbox in editable DataTable?

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I use PrimeNG DataTable in editable mode. By default there is a single line text box in each cell.

I use `word-wrap: break-word;` style in my datatable, the result is the following:
[image]

However, when I enter **editing** mode there is only **one** line:
[image]

The question is how do I make it look like in the 1 picture (**multiline**) to make it more convenient for user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the editor template for that column and replace the basic *input* with a *textarea* for instance :

```
<p-column field="vin" header="Vin" [editable]="true">
  <ng-template let-col let-car="rowData" pTemplate="editor">
        <textarea [(ngModel)]="car[col.field]" appendTo="body"></textarea>
    </ng-template>
</p-column>
```

Have you tried something like this ?

Comment: Yeah, it worked for me! Is it possible now to make it fit the width and the height of the cell?

Comment: You should be able to do it using CSS.